# any body provide me node.js gc log file

Tags: node.js

Can any body tell me how to redirect output trace_gc to log file in node js instead of console I gave command like this

```
node -trace_gc -trace_gc_verbose example.js
```

and also give me one example gc log file for node.js

Answer (score 3):

If you do not need to separate the output of the application itself from the gc trace you can simply redirect the output using:

```
node -trace_gc -trace_gc_verbose example.js > output.log
```

Otherwise V8 has a `--log_gc` option which output to the log file (can be defined with `--logfile` but this does not seems to output has many information as `-trace_gc`.

See `node --v8-options` for all options

Comment: redirection is not working it only redirecting code output not gc log

Comment: I tried it on my computer and all output is well in the file. Which shell do you use ?

Comment: I installed node js in my windows 7 and through command prompt i am running the command

Comment: Can you give give me sample log file

Comment: Here is the sample log file: http://pastebin.com/uRb0tpVm
I never tested output redirection on windows (only unix and linux) but this should work too as presented here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

In order to redirect all output try:
`node -trace_gc -trace_gc_verbose example.js 2>&1 output.log`

Comment: my gc log is only coming in one time , how to get gc log in a periodic interval

Comment: Also tell me details of the each field